# Getting new values from Redis on client side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redis

I'm using PHP with PHPRedis to connect to Redis.

This works fine

```
            $redis = new Redis();
            $redis->connect('localhost', 6379);
            $total = $redis->get('total');
```

Let's say $total is now 1. I then use the Redis client to increment the key 'total' so that it has a value of 2.

But now I want a user to be able to see the new value when they click a button

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload=function() {
                $('#newTotal').click(function (event) {
                        <?php
                            $redis = new Redis();
                            $redis->connect('localhost', 6379);
                            $total = $redis->get('total');
                        ?>
                        $("#updated").html("Total is now <?php echo $total; ?>");

                });
            }
        </script>
```

But this does not give the new value.

How can I connect to get the updated values?

Comment: You cannot nest PHP inside JavaScript and expect it to be executed on the client side. PHP is server-side language, you have to send an AJAX request (XMLHttpRequest). Or insert the new value to your template/whatever so JavaScript has it prepared and you just display the value onClick, but it had been already computed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand, PHP is running on the server-side and jQuery is on the client. That being said you'll need to use AJAX. The following would be one quick way to do it:

```
$('#newTotal').click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourPHPfile.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#updated").html("Total is now " + data);
        }
    });
});
```

And in the `yourPHPfile`

```
 $redis = new Redis();
 $redis->connect('localhost', 6379);
 $total = $redis->get('total');

 echo $total; //this is seen as the "data" parameter in the AJAX success
```

Comment: Thanks I tried using Ajax but was using the wrong syntax. For anyone reading the file should be in speech marks by the way.

Comment: @user2787904 -- Yup, forgot those :\ glad it helped!